# CSS to put the game player in its position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transforms

I'm making a game using React.js, and the player element is a simple image with sprite images implemented in CSS:

```css
.player {
    position: absolute;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    object-fit: none;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(calc(var(--factor) / 2)) rotate(0.02deg);
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

How would I add the `translate()` function to make the player's top left corner exactly at (0, 0)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be all the way at the top, no matter what else is on the page, position it absolute. This ignores everything *up to the next highest **positioned** element* That means it has a position other than the default. You can do that like this.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
/// You might need to adjust for your transform here though
```

oops... just saw that you already had it absolute. You were 90% of the way there.

Comment: that's not my problem, after I did scaling some of the player is being hidden in the top left corner of the page, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcacv.png, even after I did what you told me

Comment: I think we well need a `calc` functions to do it

Answer (score 0):

For this `.player` needs a wrapped element with `position: relative`, and we don't need `transform-origin` or `transform` styles:

```
.parentOfPlayer {
  position: relative;
}

.player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```